# Zend Framework composer autoload

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php

I have PHP project with the following vendors directory structure:

```
vendor
  zendframework
    zendframework
      library
       Zend
         ...
         ...
         Cache
         ...
         ...
```

When I put the following line into autoload_namespaces.php everything is ok:

```
'Zend\\Cache' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library/',
```

but this line doesn't work:

```
'Zend\\Cache' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Cache/',
```

The error is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MemcachedOptions' not found
```

What's wrong with my code? How can I load only Cache module from zend framework? Why does it work if I specify whole library folder?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Classes are loaded on demand, your application will only load classes that are used. The `autoload_namespaces.php` file is auto-generated by Composer, you should not edit it.

Comment: I try to use MemcachedOptions() class: `$options = new \Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MemcachedOptions();` and this line raises error.

Comment: Assuming you installed Zend Framework using Composer, there should be a `Zend\\` entry in `autoload_namespaces.php`. That's all you need, don't change anything else. If it isn't there, reinstall ZF using Composer.

Comment: If the first line works, what's the problem? Why not use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ZF1 classes have internal dependencies on other ZF classes. It's expecting the whole framework to be autoloaded. For every class not found error you get, you need to manually load that library too. Working through that list would be tedious, not impossible.

May I susggest an easier way forward:

Zend Framework 1.x can be installed with composer.

Add:
"require": {
"zendframework/zendframework1": "1.*"
},

to your composer.json
And do composer install from the command line.
This will download zend framework and setup the library to autoload along with everything else composer is managing.

To get your zend framework app to use the composer autoloader you'll need to edit your applications index.php file and include the composer autoloader like so:

```
require_once realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
```

Comment: Do you know how to download certain components of ZF1 without downloading the whole thing, using composer?

Comment: Those packages are all prefixed with zf1/something. Here's a list: https://packagist.org/search/?q=zf1%2F

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I need version 1.10.4, which they don't support that well.

Comment: This is a workaround for the OPs problem but doesn't answer the question.